# Can you recreate a class with an instance of that class?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a database component that I'm trying to make as general as possible. Is it possible to accomplish this:

1. Take in a custom class that I don't have the definition for
2. Recreate that class locally from the foreign instance

Basically I can't include the definition of objects that will be stored in the database but I want the database to process the raw data of whatever class passed in, store it, and be able to provide it again as an object.

Ideally I could cast it back to it's custom class when the Object gets back from the database.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish but could you make a copy of the object? new_object.deepcopy(old_object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are asking for is [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Serialzation in AS3 is possible through a few different methods. I recommend you refer to [this article](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1642) as it describes the method quite clearly.

To elaborate, once you serialize your object, you send it to the server and pair it with a key in a database. Then you can serialize it back into the original object by downloading it from the server again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to find that there are a lot of pitfalls with what you want to do. I suspect that you'll find over the long haul that you can solve the problem in other ways, since someone, somewhere needs a definition of the Class you're instantiating (you also need to think about what happens if you have two instances with conflicting definitions).

Probably a better way to go is to make your app more data driven--where every object can be built based on the data about it. If you need to be able to swap out implementations, consider storing the Class definitions in external swfs and downloading those based on paths or other information stored in the database. Again, you need to consider what will happen if the implementations collide between multiple swfs.

Can you expand on what you're trying to do? It's easier to give you clearer instructions with more information.